# StratifiedKFold results in missing labels?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-fold

I was using `StratifiedKFold` fold from `scikit-learn` and noticed missing labels. I had 7 labels initially, but after splitting using k fold cross validation, every fold had missed the labels `'1'`, and `'5'`; but after training somehow my model's confusion matrix was 7x7 (for each fold separately), how? And if its stratified, then shouldn't all values labels get separated class-wise?

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, test_size=0.25, random_state=2024)
print(y_train.value_counts())
y_train.value_counts().sum()
```

```py
OUTPUT[1]:
Label
0    1422917
3     241329
2       6864
6       1607
5       1468
1       1081
4         27
Name: count, dtype: int64
1675293
```

```py
Folds_split = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True, random_state=2024)

for i, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(Folds_split.split(X_train, y_train)):
    
    X_train_fold=  X.iloc[train_index]
    X_test_fold =  X.iloc[test_index]
    y_train_fold=  y.iloc[train_index]
    y_test_fold=  y.iloc[test_index]

    print(y_train_fold.value_counts())
    print(len(y_train_fold))
    print(y_test_fold.value_counts())
    print(len(y_test_fold))
    print(len(y_train_fold)+len(y_test_fold))
    print(len(y_train_fold)/(len(y_train_fold)+len(y_test_fold)))
```

```py
OUTPUT[2]:
Label
0    734822
3     97170
2      4547
6      1097
4        10
Name: count, dtype: int64
837646
Label
0    735395
3     96586
2      4605
6      1046
4        15
Name: count, dtype: int64
837647
1675293
0.4999997015447447
Label
0    735395
3     96586
2      4605
6      1046
4        15
Name: count, dtype: int64
837647
Label
0    734822
3     97170
2      4547
6      1097
4        10
Name: count, dtype: int64
837646
1675293
0.5000002984552553
```

Where are the counts for label `'1'` and '5'?

Comment: You are slicing the full `X` using splits from just `X_train`: replace e.g. `X_train_fold=  X.iloc[train_index]` by `X_train_fold=  X_train.iloc[train_index]`.

Answer (score 0):

As Ben Reiniger pointed out in the comments, the issue is the dataset you are using for slicing.

`X_train_fold` and `X_test_fold` are being sliced from the original `X` dataset, not from the split `X_train` dataset. Similarly, `y_train_fold` and `y_test_fold` are being sliced from the original `y` dataset. This is problematic because `X_train`, `X_test`, `y_train`, and `y_test` have already been split using `train_test_split`. When you use `StratifiedKFold` on `X_train` and `y_train`, the indices `train_index` and `test_index` are relative to these subsets, not the original `X` and `y`.

So the modified code could look like this:

```
for i, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(Folds_split.split(X_train, y_train)):
    X_train_fold = X_train.iloc[train_index]
    X_test_fold = X_train.iloc[test_index]
    y_train_fold = y_train.iloc[train_index]
    y_test_fold = y_train.iloc[test_index]
    ...
```

The absence of labels `'1'` and `'5'` in some folds is likely due to the imbalance in your dataset (as seen in `y_train.value_counts()`). If a label is very rare, it's possible that it might not appear in a particular split.

When you use the modified code, you should see the counts for labels `'1'` and `'5'` in your folds.